# How to add cookies in Portia

Tags: cookies, scrapy, portia

I am using Portia to scrape a website, but it has a popup for location selection. This JS based and hence I cannot interact with. The website stores a cookie which then disables the popup, rendering the website usable.
How do I add the cookie while browsing via Portia UI so that I can scrape it properly?